# Does an ndarray have a buffer which is mmap?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

How to tell if an ndarray has a buffer which is mmap?  I want to tell apart `x` and `y`.

```
import numpy as np
import mmap
with open("f.dat", "wb+") as f:
    f.seek(np.dtype(float).itemsize - 1, 0)
    f.write(b'\0')
    f.seek(0, 0)
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    x = np.ndarray(-1, buffer=mm)
y = np.zeros(1)
```